# RecyclerView clipToPadding = false

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, padding, android-5.0-lollipop

The android material design documentation suggests adding an 8 dp padding at the top and bottom of a list, and I personally like the idea and want to implement it. I am using the new `RecyclerView` widget to accomplish the look of a simple list. The problem that I'm having is when I set the attributes: `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` of my RecyclerView, the overscroll shadow which appears at the top and bottom of the list now has a padding too (and kind of looks bad and like an error). I've been reading that setting these attributes:

```
clipToPadding = false
scrollbarStyle = outsideOverlay
```

should do the trick for me, but it simply doesn't. The overscroll effect still begins with an 8 dp padding at the top and bottom of the screen and it really bugs me out. Am I doing something wrong here, or there is another solution for my problem? Any advice appreciated. Thx

Comment: I believe _RecyclerView.ItemDecoration_ is the class intended for implementing this kind of behaviour. Especially its _getItemOffsets_ documentation sounds something that could be used to add padding at both ends of the contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug, will be fixed when RecyclerView is released.

Comment: Ok, if that's the case.. Can you just send a link of the reported bug (if it is reported). I'll accept your answer..

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=261    This is the link to issue but I don't think it is fixed yet!

Comment: It's Android - The likelihood of a bug getting fixed is 1 in 4 in the first year of the bug's life.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier is that bug fixed or still it is there. I am still getting that bug

Answer (score 8):

Adding `clipToPadding` as false works on latest releases

```
  android:clipToPadding="false"
```

I'm using `recylerview` version

```
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
```

Comment: @Libin it is not working even in latest library. I have updated the version of recyclerView that you have mention and also added clipTpPadding="false" to recyclerView and view pager in which it is getting loaded. But still the issue is there. Please guide me how to resolved it if you have already resolved it.

Comment: @Sandra i you can able to help me as well, that will be great.

Comment: I just set the clipToPadding=false attribute on the recycler view and that did it for me. I don't know if you should set this attribute to the view pager also..maybe you should try without it.

Answer (score -1):

This method will give the padding to the last position view

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>{

public int getItemType(int position){

if(arrayList.size()-1==position){

return ITEM_TYPE;
}

return 0;
}

public MyHolder onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder,int position){

if(getItemViewType(position)==ITEM_TYPE){
holder.itemView.setPadding(0,0,0,10);
}

}
```